# On the set of divergence to infinity for sequences of positive continuous functions

Tags: real-analysis

This question is motivated by this [one](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/34371/on-the-existence-of-a-sequence-of-positive-continuous-functions) on MathOverflow, which contains an example of a sequence $(f_n)$ of positive continuous functions on $\mathbb{R}$ such that
$$f_n(x) \rightarrow \infty$$
if and only if $x \in \mathbb{Q}$.

My question is the following :

For a given sequence of positive continuous functions $(f_n)$ on $\mathbb{R}$, denote by $S((f_n))$ the set of divergence to $\infty$ :
$$S((f_n)):=\{ x \in \mathbb{R} : f_n(x) \rightarrow \infty \}.$$

Is there a necessary and sufficient condition for a given set $S$ to be $S((f_n))$ for some sequence $(f_n)$?

Note that
$$S((f_n)) = \bigcap_{N} \bigcup_{k} \bigcap_{n \geq k} \{x: f_n(x)>N\},$$
so a necessary condition is that $S$ must be a countable intersection of countable unions of $G_{\delta}'s$...

Comment: A small improvement: since $S((f_n))=\bigcap_N \bigcup_k \bigcap_{n\ge k}\{x\colon f_n(x)\ge N\}$, the set $S$ is a countable intersection of countable unions of **closed** sets, so a countable intersection of $F_\sigma$s. Also known as $F_{\sigma\delta}$, I believe. This might also be sufficient...

Comment: That's right, thank you for the comment!

Comment: If $g_n:\mathbb R\to[0,1]$ for each $n$, and $f_n= \frac{1}{1-\frac{n}{n+1}g_n}$, then $(f_n(x))\to\infty$ if and only if $(g_n(x))\to 1$.  My thought was that it might be easier to work with functions bounded by $1$ and the set where they converge to $1$.

Comment: @Jonas Meyer : Good remark, thank you for the comment.

Comment: Just to note that this question has now been cross-posted to MathOverflow: http://mathoverflow.net/questions/97654/on-the-set-of-divergence-to-infinity-for-sequences-of-positive-continuous-functio

Comment: @Willie Wong : Thank you for adding the link to the MO version, I forgot to do it!

Comment: No prob. Very nice question by the way.

Comment: ...MO, where it received a complete answer.